# Playwright does not see the running webserver

Tags: process, webserver, port, playwright

Simple setup with Angular app.

When trying to run the tests, playwright fails to find the running app on 'http://localhost:4200' => tries to spin it up again => fails to do so => timeout.

Replacing `url: http://localhost:4200/`, with `port: 4200` fixes the issue. Not sure if it's relevant, but issue is mostly happening on M2 MacBooks, so it might have something to do with how it handles network/terminals etc.

```
`webServer: [
    {
      command: 'nx serve',
      url: 'http://localhost:4200/', //problem was here
      timeout: 600 * 1000,
      reuseExistingServer: true,
    },
  ],`
```

Posting this so other can save few days that took us to figure it out =)

**Solution:** Change the `url` to `port`

Comment: Where is this config from? Please create an answer for this question instead of answering directly in the question.

Comment: Solutions [shouldn't be in questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262806/is-it-ok-for-users-to-edit-the-accepted-answer-into-their-question). Please ask a normal question, then post a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) in the answer area if you want to answer it.

Comment: okay, if you want a question to answer.... Why Playwright does not see the working webserver on localhost:4200 ?

Comment: actually it would be good to have an answer placed as an answer. Not in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing url: http://localhost:4200/, with port: 4200 fixes the issue. Not sure if it's relevant, but issue is mostly happening on M2 MacBooks, so it might have something to do with how it handles network/terminals etc.